# Sender Name in Sendgrid Python package

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send Emails using Sendgrid Python package.

Sendgrid package mail function:

```
class Mail(object):
    """Creates the response body for v3/mail/send"""

    def __init__(
            self,
            from_email=None,
            to_emails=None,
            subject=None,
            plain_text_content=None,
            html_content=None,
            amp_html_content=None,
            global_substitutions=None,
            is_multiple=False):
            ........
```

We are using it as:

```
message = Mail(
    from_email=self.current_from_email,
    to_emails=self.current_to_emails,
    subject=s_subject.format(...),
    html_content=s_body.format(...)
 )
```

In mail's function there is no way to set Sender's name.

Then, how can I set sender's name?

Answer (score 17):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

To set the name of a sender, you have a couple of options. Firstly, you can format the email address like this `Sender name <sender_email@example.com>`.

Alternatively, you can import `Email`, or `From` and `To`, from the helpers and use that instead:

```py
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import From, To

from_email = From("sender_email@example.com", "Sender Name")
to_email = To("receiver_email@example.com", "Receiver Name")

message = Mail(from_email, to_email, "Subject", "Content")
```

See [the example in the GitHub README](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python#with-mail-helper-class) for more class helpers you can use.

Comment: It shows me the error `TypeError: object of type 'From' has no len()`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think this likely needs some more context @MyCar, can you ask a new question and fill in as many details as you can about the error you are seeing?